# Is there any way to search tweet by url?

Tags: python

https://twitter.com/metakongz_G/status/1502223321009913857?t=PVLQS03E87nARHxbOMBjDQ&s=19

I have this target url. I want to get this tweet's retweets and comments using tweepy.
However it seems to be like tweepy does not support searching with url. How can I?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. Try to use automated browsers: [There is an interesting manual that can help with Selenium and Python](https://dev.to/swyx/scraping-my-twitter-social-graph-with-python-and-selenium--hn8)
2. Use official or unofficial Twitter APIs, [example from RapidAPI](https://rapidapi.com/Glavier/api/twitter135/)
3. Get tweet id from url (numbers between "/status/" and "?") and use tweepy by id [like here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-api-retweets-in-tweepy/):

```py
url = "https://twitter.com/metakongz_G/status/1502223321009913857?t=PVLQS03E87nARHxbOMBjDQ&s=19"
id = url.split("/status/")[1].split("?")[0]
print(id)
```